# rmarkdown: yaml references to bibliography

Tags: r-markdown

In [rmarkdown/bibliography](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html#unused_references_(nocite)), how can I convert a bunch of YAML encoded references into one of the files formats accepted by the bibliography?

I am currently using:

```
references:
- id: fenner2012a
  title: One-click science marketing
  author:
  - family: Fenner
    given: Martin
  container-title: Nature Materials
  volume: 11
  URL: 'http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nmat3283'
  DOI: 10.1038/nmat3283
  issue: 4
  publisher: Nature Publishing Group
  page: 261-263
  type: article-journal
  issued:
    year: 2012
    month: 3
```

and would like to use:

```
bibliography: bibliography.???
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to copy the references into a .yaml file. AND to add

```
---
references:
```

at the start of the file and `---` at the end of the file